# How to display the trimmed value and the full value of a field in a same node

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a content type with a text field that i want to render trimmed and full in the same node.

I've set my field to "trimmed" and rendered it in my node.tpl.php using
`<?php print render($content['field_image_desc']); ?>`

Now i need to render the same field but not trimmed (to display it in an overlay div).

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 3):

i answer myself:

inside node.tpl.php, this is rendering a trimmed version of my field

```
<?php 
     print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_myfieldname', array(
        'label'=>'hidden', 
        'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed', 
        'settings'=>array('trim_length' => 30),
    )));
?>
```

and then i render my 'default' format field like always

```
<?php print render($content['field_image_desc']); ?>
```

Comment: Yes. Upboats for you, welcome to drupal.stackexchange. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, your obviously going to want some sort of event to open the overlay so create a link field. Display the full content in the overlay with a different view mode.

Comment: ok, thanks ! in fact the problem was that i din't know how to render view modes in a node.tpl.php.